# I'm trying to get the address of my smart contract using truffle and typescript and I get a type error

Tags: typescript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, truffle

I'm trying to get the address of my smart contract using truffle and typescript and I get a type error:

method where the error occurs:

```
import SmartContractJson from "../../contractsdeployed/Main.json"

    async loadSmartContracts() {
        const networkId = await this.web3.eth.net.getId()
        const networkData = SmartContractJson.networks[networkId]; <----  
    }
```

error description:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{ "1673876271947": { events: {}; links: {}; address: string; transactionHash: string; }; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{ "1673876271947": { events: {}; links: {}; address: string; transactionHash: string; }; }'.
    35 |        async loadSmartContracts() {
    36 |                const networkId = await this.web3.eth.net.getId()
  > 37 |                const networkData = SmartContractJson.networks[networkId];
       |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    38 |        }
    39 | }
```

Comment: can you try `String(networkId)`

Comment: try casting it to type like that and out of all possible ways and nothing works, it keeps saying it's an any, it's very strange

Comment: If I import it to the smartcontract in the following way, everything works correctly:

const SmartContractJSON = require( "../../contractsdeployed/Main.json");

Answer (score 0):

If I import it to the smartcontract in the following way, everything works correctly:

```
const SmartContractJSON = require( "../../contractsdeployed/Main.json");
```

is very strange